# Which of the two variables is more independent from a third one

Tags: independence, ranking

I am new in general to statistics and was wondering if there is way to measure this:
Assume these are my variables:

```
x:
0.01336396156
0.01296497716
0.006340178031
0.02447376938

y:
-0.004196114594
0.01246864056
0.01608681989
-0.007968929671

z:
-0.00755313789
0.01497715597
0.0486919239
-0.04139268516
```

If these values are plotted, they look like this:
Blue: x, Red: z, Yellow: y
[image]

x and y are both generally considered to be dependent on z. Its is degree of dependence that I am after. Also each instance of the variable (x,y) could be more or less dependent on z
I want to get cumulative ranking of "independence". So from the graph its straight forward that *Blue (x) is more independent* than Yellow(y) on z. So I was to rank, x would have a higher rank than y.

Is there a good statistical way of achieving this?

Comment: In a linear algebra setting or in statistics in general, independence is a binary: two variables are either independent or not. If you want degrees of independence, you would need to define what that is. It's an intriguing concept, but what do you have in mind?

Comment: Would a Pearson correlation coefficient suit your needs?

Comment: @Bernhard thank you, i think that is indeed suitable, I will explore it

Comment: @Bernhard My idea was to calculate daily returns as compared to daily returns of index, to what extent its correlated. I found this article: https://quantdare.com/correlation-prices-returns/ your thoughts on this?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I did not understand "define what that is", could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sounds like you just did (via using correlation coefficients). In the context of my sentence, I meant that you should define the term "degrees of independence", or what you mean by "more independent" and "less independent".

Comment: :thumbsup thanks